# Java JPanel Arc formation around edge of circle

Tags: java, jpanel

Im trying to draw an arc that stretches around part of the circle. Im confused on how to use the DrawArc method. I read few articles online and to simply put, im confused on how the parameters exactly work. My circle is centered at 100, 100 with radius of 50. How would i use the drawArc method to draw an arc that overlaps the circle ? Any thoughts would be highly appreciated

Comment: Back in the day I wrote an arc generator, but I can't find the code. As I recall, I did this using java.awt.Area, starting with a circle, and then subtracting another circle from it. Sorry, I know this isn't much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading articles is good, but you should always read a method's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawArc-int-int-int-int-int-int-).

The drawArc method does not take a center and radius as arguments.  Instead, it takes a rectangle.  The x and y arguments are the upper-left corner of that rectangle;  the width and height are the horizontal and vertical diameters of your arc's ellipse.

You can just do the math yourself:

```
int centerX = 100;
int centerY = 100;
int radius = 50;
graphics.drawArc(centerX - radius,
                 centerY - radius,
                 radius * 2,
                 radius * 2,
                 startAngle,
                 span);
```

Note that the final argument is the number of degrees the arc spans, not the absolute end angle.